# Overlapping buttons in android

Tags: java, android

In android, I am trying to add buttons programatically, but all the buttons that are added are overlapping. The code I am using is somewhat like this:

```
for(int i = (int) 'a'; i <= (int) 'z'; i++)
{
    Button button = new Button(this);
    char letter = (char)i;
    String letterOnButton = Character.toString(letter);
    button.setText(letterOnButton);
    RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.dynbuttons);
    LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    rl.addView(button,lp);
}
```

It does not throw a button, but I only get to see the "z" button.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: you can set `button.setRight(someIntegerValue);` for each `button`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned above LinearLayout would be the best solution, but if u still want to use RelativeLayout, try setting an id to each button and inflate the subsequent with the parameter   RIGHT_OF/BELOW..as suggested above, parameter "layout_alignLeft" will produce the same effect, i.e inflate all buttons in the same position

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
        int id = 0;

        for (int i = (int) 'a'; i <= (int) 'z'; i++) {
            Button button = new Button(this);
            char letter = (char) i;
            String letterOnButton = Character.toString(letter);
            button.setText(letterOnButton);
            button.setId(i);
            LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, id);
            rl.addView(button, lp);
            id = i;
        }
```

Comment: When I do this, the buttons keep getting placed next to eachother, but go off-screen. Any idea on how to solve that issue?

Comment: Since you want your buttons to be placed next to other, just put that RelativeLayout inside a HorizontalScrollView

Comment: I wanted them to be horizontal as long as they are on even, but I solved it, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a `LinearLayout` instead of a `RelativeLayout`, something like this:

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.dynbuttons);
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
for(int i = (int) 'a'; i <= (int) 'z'; i++) {
    Button button = new Button(this);
    char letter = (char)i;
    String letterOnButton = Character.toString(letter);
    button.setText(letterOnButton);
    ll.addView(button,lp);
}
```

If you still want to use a `RelativeLayout` you have to set the parameter `layout_alignLeft` for each button.